# FreeIPA user not executing .bashrc or .bash_profile

Tags: bash, freeipa

I've found that users created in FreeIPA don't execute ~/.bashrc or ~/bash_profile when they log in. However, /etc/bashrc and /etc/profiles are executed.

Alternatively, I have created a local user, and both files are executed, so it's something related to FreeIPA.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Comment: Well, `.bashrc` is not supposed to be executed during the login process anyway. It is only run for an interactive non-login-shell. Furthermore, the files `/etc/bashrc` and ~/bash_profile should never be executed. However, a login shell should run `~/.bash_profile`. Can you verify this, by creating this file and then manually run a `bash --login` from the command line?

Comment: One more idea: From your behaviour, I wonder whether you are really in bash. How did you verify that this is bash what you are running under FreeIPA?

Comment: You're right! sh instead of bash was being used. I've set bash as the default shell and now everything is working. Thanks!